# Scalaz Task not starting

Tags: scala, task, yield, scalaz

I'm trying to make an asyncronous call using scalaz Task.

For some strange reason whenever I attempt to call methodA, although I get a scalaz.concurrent.Task returned I never see the 2nd print statement which leads me to believe that the asynchronous call is never returned. Is there something that I'm missing that is required in order for me to start the task?

```
for {
    foo <- println("we are in this for loop!").asAsyncSuccess()
    authenticatedUser <- methodA(parameterA)
    foo2 <- println("we are out of this this call!").asAsyncSuccess()
} yield {
    authenticatedUser
}


def methodA(parameterA: SomeType): Task[User]
```

Comment: Why are you even using `Task` in the first place?

Comment: Actually I decided to take another route using Future instead.  Thanks.

Comment: If the Task returned by `methodA` is failed due to any exception, then second print statement will be never gets executed.

Answer (score 0):

First off, Scalaz `Task` is lazy: it won't start when you create it or get from some method. It's by design and allows `Task`s to combine well. It's not intended to start until you fully assemble your entire program into single main `Task`, so when you're done, you need to manually start an aggregated `Task` using one of the `perform` methods, like `unsafePerformSync` that will wait for the result of aggregate async computation on a current thread:

```
(for {
    foo <- println("we are in this for loop!").asAsyncSuccess()
    authenticatedUser <- methodA(parameterA)
    foo2 <- println("we are out of this this call!").asAsyncSuccess()
} yield {
    authenticatedUser
}).unsafePerformSync
```

As you can see from your original code, you've never started any `Task`. However, you've mentioned that first `println` printed its message to console. This may be related to `asAsyncSuccess` method: I've not found it in Scalaz, so I assume it's in implicit class somewhere in your code:

```
implicit class TaskOps[A](val a: A) extends AnyVal {
  def asAsyncSuccess(): Task[A] = Task(a)
}
```

If you write a helper implicit class like this, it won't convert an effectful expression into lazy `Task` action, despite the fact that `Task.apply`
is [call-by-name](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html#by-name-parameters). It will only convert its result, which happens to be just `Unit`, because its own parameter `a` is not call-by-name. To work as intended, it needs to be like the following:

```
implicit class TaskOps[A](a: => A) {
  def asAsyncSuccess(): Task[A] = Task(a)
}
```

You may also ask why first `println` prints something while second isn't. This is related to [`for`-comprehensions desugaring](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#for-comprehensions-and-for-loops) into method calls. Specifically, compiler turns your code into this:

```
println("we are in this for loop!").asAsyncSuccess().flatMap(foo =>
  methodA(parameterA).flatMap(authenticatedUser =>
    println("we are out of this this call!").asAsyncSuccess().map(foo2 =>
      authenticatedUser)))
```

If `asAsyncSuccess` doesn't respect intended `Task` semantics, first `println` gets executed immediately. But its result is then wrapped into `Task` that is, essentially, just a wrapper over start function, and `flatMap` implementation on it just combines such functions together without running them. So, `methodA` or second `println` won't be executed until you call `unsafePerformSync` or other `perform` helper method. Note, however, that second `println` will still be executed earlier than it should according to `Task` semantics, just not *that* earlier.